# Best way in C to test whether `foo` is executable at the command line?

Tags: c

In C, what is the best way to find out if `foo` is available at the command line to execute on the host? If I were at the bash command line, I'd run `type foo`. In C, I could do `type foo` as a *system call* and check the exit status. But it's a good idea to avoid system calls when possible, right? Is there a better way?

My program may have to do a system command that eventually would run `foo` inside a shell script. (It's someone else's world and they supposedly use `foo`.) But if it can tell at the start that `foo` would be unavailable, it can avoid doing a lot of unnecessary computation because no `foo` means failure is certain.

Comment: I don't think there's a sensical way to avoid a system call at some point along the way here, unfortunately.

Comment: By your phrase, "available on the host", what exactly do you mean?  Is `foo` an executable? a data file?  what??

Comment: Either duplicate the OS's logic for determining if a program is present on the path, or use the OS's logic. I recommend using the OS's logic.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: you could scan the path like `which` does. That wouldn't solve built-in & aliases from the shell, though.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to avoid a syscall? I assume that you want to execute the command if it exists?

Comment: My general advice is "don't do this". You can never know what the shell script will do to run `foo`; for example, maybe it gets updated someday to set its own PATH. Or to use a different version of `foo`. Or who-knows-what. If the script really needs to fail early when `foo` is not present, that logic belongs in the script itself, not your program. Good designs aim for high cohesion and low coupling; what you describe violates both.

Comment: Try to execute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` (and its cousin, `which`) are commands provided by most Unix-like OS's and also implemented by most shells as an intrinsic.

You could simply invoke those commands by starting a child process from your program, and then read their output. If you want to rely on the behavior of a shell's version of the command, then you must start a child process that launches that shell, then command it to run `type` or `which`. If you'd rather not use child processes, then you must re-implement their logic in your program.

Using [the FreeBSD implementation of which](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.bin/which/which.c) as a guide, we can see the basic steps for doing this:

- Read the value of the `$PATH` environment variable.
- Split apart `$PATH` into the various directories that it contains.
- Test to see if the target file/program exists at one of the various sub directories in path.

And in code:

Read `$PATH` from the env:

```
if ((p = getenv("PATH")) == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Call `print_matches` with one of the arguments to `which`, providing the entire value of the `$PATH`:

```
while (argc > 0) {
    memcpy(path, p, pathlen);

    if (strlen(*argv) >= FILENAME_MAX ||
        print_matches(path, *argv) == -1)
        status = EXIT_FAILURE;
...
```

In `print_matches`, break apart the `$PATH` variable by splitting on the `:` character:

```
while ((d = strsep(&path, ":")) != NULL) {
```

And for each directory, concatenate the target program to the directory (checking to make sure the string doesn't become too big):

```
if (snprintf(candidate, sizeof(candidate), "%s/%s", d,
        filename) >= (int)sizeof(candidate))
             continue;
```

And then test to see if that file exists:

```
if (is_there(candidate)) {
```

Comment: One more thing. Check that that file is an executable.